# Is it possible to dynamically insert a value of an object parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure this out but I haven't been able to find an answer that relates to my issue.

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically enter a value of an object parameter from an input box?

Example:

```
    <form name="myform">

    <input type="visibile" name="formvar" value="">
</form>

    <object id="myobject">
       <param name="color" value="{input destination}" />
```

I'm basically wondering if its possible to dynamically add values into the "input destination"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once the `object` is created (when page get loaded), the `param`s are passed to that object. So you aren't be able to change the "input destination" after that.

You could delay the creation of `object` till the `input` is changed like followings.

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="visibile" name="formvar" value="" onchange="createObject(value)">
</form>
<script>
    function createObject(value) {
        document.getElementById('document_container').innerHTML = 
        '<object id="myobject">' +
            '<param name="color" value="' + value + '"/>' +
        '</object>';
    }
</script>
<div id="object_container"></div>
```

The only drawback is that `object` will created over and over again once the `input` is changed.

Another option is to ensure the `object` plugin offers some APIs which accept setting new parameters, for example `myobject.setParam('color', value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this object:

http://www.jsclasses.org/package/274-JavaScript-Template-engine-that-takes-objects-as-parameters.html

or on github

https://github.com/blauharley/TemplateJS

It is able to insert a value of an JSON-Object into a string like this:

```
 var str = '<object id="myobject"> <param name="color" value="{input}{destination}" />...';

 var obj = [{ input: { destination: 'a value'} }]
 var templ = new TemplateJS();

 templ.insertTemplate(obj,str,'#html-id-to-insert-output');
```

The third parameter ('#html-id-to-insert-output') is used for inserting the output of the insertTemplate-methode.

Hope this helps.